# Cypress hot reload fails

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I have a component library that runs Cypress.  The initial test runs fine, but when I change a file the tests permanently fail.  The page will display:

`Cannot GET /__cypress/src/index.html`

The CLI will post:
`GET /__cypress/iframes/C:/Users/anthony.mandra/proj/widgetaur/src/Footer/Footer.spec.tsx 404 7.034 ms - 163`

The console after the hot reload:
`GET http://localhost:50402/__cypress/iframes/C:/Users/anthony.mandra/proj/widgetaur/src/Footer/Footer.spec.tsx 404 (Not Found)`

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by clearing the cache and restarting cypress: `rm -r .next/cache && npx cypress run-ct`. See more on https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/20073.